# Synchronously process a nested array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am refactoring some code that crawls some web pages (removing "callback hell"), and want **a three second delay between each request**. Here is the request function:

```
const getHTML = function(page, i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            api.makeAPIGetRequest(page).then((html) => {
                resolve(html);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            })
        }, i * 3000);
    });
}
```

I am traversing an array of objects then an array:

```
let p = [
    {
        location: 'England',
        pages: [1, 3, 5]
    },
    {
        location: 'Scotland',
        pages: [2, 4, 6]
    }
];
```

The problem is is that the output is random (because of the delay):

```
Page 1 - Loaded
Page 2 - Loaded
Page 5 - Loaded
Page 4 - Loaded
Page 3 - Loaded
Page 6 - Loaded
```

It should be:

```
Page 1 - Loaded
Page 3 - Loaded
Page 5 - Loaded
Page 2 - Loaded
Page 4 - Loaded
Page 6 - Loaded
```

Here is my code:

```
p.map(async (data) => {
    await crawlLocationPages(data);
})

function crawlLocationPages(data) {

    return Promise.all(
        data.pages.map(async (page, i) => {
            await getHTML(page, i).then((html) => { // <-- waits 3 seconds
                console.log('Page ' + page + ' - Loaded' );
            });

        })
    ).then(() => {

    })

};
```

I would rather keep the object and array model as it is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you didn't include the value of _delay in your question, I assume it is `1000`ms, right?

Comment: 3000ms - I would like a 3 second delay between each page request

Comment: You can store the all the API responses in an array and print only after all the requests are completed. Or you can print as the response comes just maintain an array of all the responses already printed and check check before printing. If the previous response is not yet printed, put the response in an object and print it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` doesn't work inside `.map` and `.forEach`, but it does work inside `for` loops. And of course, it has to be inside an `async` function.

```
const run = async () => {
    for(let data of p){
        await crawlLocationPages(data);
    }
}

const crawlLocationPages = async data => {
    for(let page of data.pages){
        const html = await getHTML(page);
        console.log('Page ' + page + ' - Loaded - HTML = ', html );
        await pause();
    }
}

const pause = () => new Promise( (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000) );

run()
```

Comment: Nice solution. I went with ES6 generators because the `getHTML` function is out of my scope at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might be less confusing but only works if each request take no longer than 3 seconds.

```js
pages = p.flatMap(location => location.pages);
page = 0;
var interval = setInterval(() => {
  if(page === pages.length){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  api.makeAPIGetRequest(pages[page++]).then((html) => {
    console.log('Page ' + page + ' - Loaded' );
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}, 3000);
```

Or call next inside `then`

```js
function getPage(pages, i) {
    const ts = Date.now();
    api.makeAPIGetRequest(pages[i++]).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        if(i < pages.length) {
            const delay = Math.max(3000 - (Date.now() - ts), 0);
            setTimeout(getPage(pages, i), delay);
        }        
    })
}

pages = p.flatMap(location => location.pages);
getPages(pages, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using ES6 generators and `yield`.

```
function* crawlGenerator() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= (p.length - 1); i++) {

        yield crawlLocationPages(p[i]);
    }

}

let crawl = crawlGenerator();
crawl.next();

function crawlLocationPages(data) {

    return Promise.all(
        data.pages.map(async (page, i) => {
            await getHTML(page, i).then((html) => { // <-- waits 3 seconds
                console.log('Page ' + page + ' - Loaded' );
            });

        })
    ).then(() => {
        crawl.next();
    })

};
```

More information here: https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators